# Why a singleView application doesn't load a storyboard if a storyboard is added later to the project?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I created a new singleView application without storyboard (say FirstProject) and another single view application with storyboard (say SecondProject)and then added a storyboard in the application which didn't have a storyboard previously.
Then I went in the FirstProject and changed the class of the storyboard to the viewcontroller class in identity inspector.
After that I opened other files in the two projects individually and made changes in the code to be same in the corresponding files in the two projects.

Now when I run the project which had storyboard at the time of creation shows a white blank screen but the other application (in which storyboard was added later) shows just a black screen with no errors and no warnings.. What is the difference in these two files?

What is it that I am missing. How to tell an application that it should now load its view from storyboard and not from a XIB file as there is none?

Comment: Did you change all the files?

Comment: Did you delete the XIB file from project Navigator?

Comment: Yes I made the files to exactly the same in both projects and I also deleted the XIB file from the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I second the "Good Job" building from scratch to truly Grok storyboards.

You need to delete the template code and just `return YES;` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

**Complete Process**

- Create a new project using the "Empty Application" template.
- New File, User Interface, Storyboard
- Set the storyboard in the targets summery  (updates the info.plist)
- Delete the template code and just `return YES;` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had already removed everything from the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` function. I included the name of the storyboard in the traget summary as shown in the second screen shot and it worked.. Thanks a lot Gayle.

Comment: I have another question. In the first screen shot how did you compare two files and showed the difference in them in XCode. Is there an option in Xcode to compare two files?

Comment: Got it.. that view comes by clicking the third button in the editor secition at the top right in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

The way that a storyboard application knows to use the storyboard at launch time is that the Info.plist file contains an entry pointing to the main storyboard. You need to set that up. The "Main storyboard file base name" (`UIMainStoryboardFile`) must match the base name of the storyboard file; the system sees this and loads the designated storyboard file automatically as the app launches.

Also you need to make sure that the initial view controller in the storyboard is marked as the initial view controller.

Comment: But I had Compared the info.plist files also and didn't find any difference in these two files also.

Comment: Nevertheless you will see that I'm right about this entry in the info.plist. By the way, what you are doing is a Very Good Thing! It is really good to try to build a storyboard-based project from scratch, so that you see that the template isn't some kind of magic. You should be able to build *all* template project types from scratch! Stay with it.

Comment: By the way, if there is no xib, you will need to design the view controller in the storyboard. Try giving the view controller's view a green background or something distinctive like that, so you will know it is loading!